# having a different IP for docker container?

Tags: docker

I don't want my docker container to have the same IP as my host. Is it possible to assign an IP?
The guides I read seems to indicate creating a subnet but it seems only docker container within the same subnets will be able to communicate with each other.

I want the docker container to be the same subnet as the host but just a different IP.

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of your network router, IP addresses are assigned to *hosts*.  The standard networking model doesn't have a way to assign an IP address to a Docker container, or a process, or a thread, or another piece smaller than an entire host.

```
+-------------+                  +------------------+
| 192.168.1.1 |  192.168.1.0/24  | 192.168.1.2      |
| Router      | <-------+------> | Host             |
+-------------+         |        |   nginx          |
                        :        |   sshd           |
                        :        |   docker run ... |
                        v        +------------------+
```

Often there is a way to assign a second IP address to the host (on Linux this feature is called "IP aliasing").  If you can do this, then the `docker run -p` option lets you specify which specific IP address to listen on

```sh
# Assuming the host is already configured with an interface
# on 192.168.1.100, forward port 80 there to port 8000
docker run -p 192.168.1.100:80:8000 my-image
```

In general, though, Docker containers don't have independent externally-visible IP addresses any more than other host server-type processes do.

Comment: will look at IP aliasing. I am running docker on debian 10

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, All IP addresses must to be recognized by HOST's network stack. It's impossible to have IP address on container only without enabling a special mode in the hardware interface(or its driver)

AFAIK, Using host network mode make the container have **all** IP address host have.

Comment: ok that means this can't be done. I have nextcloud docker container working only on 443 ... so I basically cannot run any other stuff on 443

Comment: You can use -p 444:443 when you start your container and use https://10.0.0.78:444/ to talk to your nextcloud docker.

Answer (score 0):

Hello maybe its being a while but i just made something like this, what i did is i made a dummy interface for each container

```
host:172.17.77.10
dummy1:172.17.77.11
dummy2:172.17.77.12
dummy3:172.17.77.13
```

and all i had to do is in the services configuration just bind each service or daemon in the container or in the host to the correspondent IP of course you have to run your docker with the --net=host option

```
apache host: listen 172.17.77.10:80
apache docker1: listen 172.17.77.11:80
```

and so on so on with all the services
i hope it helps